# Angular works in strange way

Tags: angularjs

The following is the code of mine. In this I've used ng-click instead of ng-href for some reason.

I've used **ng-click like** `ng-click="navigateUrl('link{{$index+1}}')"`. In the view, the value is showing correctly like navigateUrl('link2'). But when I receive it in the controller, I am getting `'link{{$index+1}}'`.

Here My confusion is that was working code. After somedays, i got the issue like this. So I've reverted the code from **ng-click to ng-href**. I want to know where I've made mistake and what is the reason for this issue?

```
<li ng-repeat="item in commonObject.itmes" ng-click="commonObject.sideBarIsCollapsed=!commonObject.sideBarIsCollapsed">

    <a class="cursorPointer" ng-href="#/link{{$index+1}}" title="{{item.name}}" 
        ng-if="item.isSelected && item.reportId!=3">

        <i class="glyph-icon icon-linecons-tv"></i>
        <span> {{item.name}}</span>
    </a>

</li>
```

Comment: `ng-click="navigateUrl('link{{$index+1}}')"` should be `ng-click="navigateUrl("link"+($index+1))"`. ng-click takes an expression without interpolation

Comment: This won't be a good implementation. You may face syntax error.